# Display cells values in specified order

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to make a report using excel, with the result like this :

Data example:

> column A is ten product name : apple, pear, melon, etc..
>
> column B is ten product code : appl, pir, mln, etc..
>
> column C is where i input the string/value such as : appl / mln
>
> column D is where the formula result such as : APPLE and MELON

The formula i'm using in column D is :

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$1,$C1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$2,$C1))),
CONCATENATE($A$1," AND ",$A$2),
IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$2,$C1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$1,$C1))),
CONCATENATE($A$2, " AND ", $A$1),""))
```

When i input product code "appl / pir" in column C1 it shows the result "apple and pear". This is correct result.

But when I input product code "pir / appl" in column C1 it doesn't change the result to "pear and apple", instead it remain "apple and pear"

How to achieve the result to display "pear and apple"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not the formula you are using, because it's not valid. Please edit your post and explain your case clearly, including the example of data stored in your worksheet.

Comment: okay please wait i will explain more

Comment: @EganWolf and yes that is exactly the formula I'm using now..and i wanna know how to improve it so it will find on exact match and position spesified

Comment: That can't be true, as there are 14 opening brackets `(` and 12 closing brackets `)`.

Comment: sorry @EganWolf, i edited again to correcting the bracket..

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$1,$C1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$2,$C1))),
    IF(SEARCH($B$1,$C1)<=SEARCH($B$2,$C1),
        CONCATENATE($A$1," AND ",$A$2),
        CONCATENATE($A$2," AND ",$A$1)),
    "")
```

In your formula it's not possible to have condition in first `IF` false and in second `IF` true. It's exactly the same condition. Instead, you can compare positions of codes in your string.

Comment: thank you @EganWolf for your answer, but i tried to apply your formula and the formula works for displaying the result "pear and apple" but when i change the input to "appl / pir" again, the result stay at "pear and apple" and doesn't change to "apple and pear"

Comment: nvm, found it..just need change the "<=" to ">=" thank you for the formula :)